# Multiple threads update global variables periodically while third thread waiting to read

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, posix

I have two threads A,B periodically update two global sensor reading variables, they execute the same routine. and third thread C will make some calculation on those values as soon as they are updated. I set some condition variable that when A & B both updated the global variables, C will read right away. I am worried that thread C missed some sensor reading due to it uses while loop's polling is arranged after the new A,B updates. I am not sure my worries is necessary, because I a newbie to pthread.
My development environment is a embedded linux board and I am learning pthread currently.
Is there a better way than setting two conditional variables for each global variables.

Comment: Better in what way? What issue do you have with condition variables? Do you have issues with code complexity? Performance? Assurance of correctness? Is there actual contention? Or is this access just occasional and so all that matters is correctness? (If so, why not just use a mutex?)

Comment: Is it important for C to not miss updates? For example is it OK for sensor A's reading to be updated twice before C gets around to doing something with it (so C only concerns itself with the most recent reading) or is that unacceptable?  If the latter, then a queue that can hold more than one reading may be necessary or you may need to block the producer thread (A or B) until C gets around to consuming the update.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one mutex, one condition variable, and one predicate integer generation counter (just a regular integer initialized to zero). The logic works like this:

To update the value: Lock the mutex. Update the value. Increment the predicate integer. Broadcast the condition variable. Release the mutex.

To read the current value: Lock the mutex. Make a copy of the value of the predicate integer generation counter. Read the value. Release the mutex.

To check for a new value: Lock the mutex. Check the predicate integer against the value you copied when you last read the value. If it's different, there is a new value. Release the mutex.

To wait for a new value: Lock the mutex. While the predicate integer still holds the value it held when you last read a value, block on the condition variable releasing the mutex. Copy the new predicate integer for your next wait. Note the new value. Release the mutex.

Comment: predicate integer risks overflow, I set flags instead, and turn them after reading is finished.

Comment: Overflow is harmless as the value will still change. But if you're really paranoid, you can switch it back to zero once it gets over a billion.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you'd want one generation counter (or flags) for each of the two values so C can determine which reading (or that both) was updated.

Comment: You might. And if you want threads to be able to wait for a particular variable to update, you might want two condition variables. Those are all choices you can make in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is a plain mutex.

```
pthread_mutex_t lockX = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

[...]

pthread_mutex_lock(lockX);
// do things with shared variable
pthread_mutex_unlock(lockX);
```

This applies to reading and writing, as even with a single int it is possible for thread A to read **half** a value, then thread B writes to the same variable, and thread B continues to read the other half, resulting in a "value" which never existed.

You don't *have* to use globals with threads, BTW.  You can pass a struct pointer with anything in it to the thread function.

Comment: Could you enlighten me when you say " thread A to read half a value, then thread B writes to the same variable, and thread B continues to read the other half, resulting in a "value" which never existed."

Comment: It's exactly what he said. Without proper synchronization, a read and a write could overlap, resulting in reading half the old value and half the new value. Say a variable holds the value "93" and you are writing "31" to it. If I'm reading at the same time as you're writing, I might read the "9" then you write "31" then I read the "1", so I think the value is "91", which it *never* was.